# Inner join on array columns from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.4, array

I have 2 tables that are related between them using integer data which is stored in arrays.

**Data table**

```
telemetria_data.historico_354677050164513

CREATE TABLE historico_354677050164513 (
    imei bigint NOT NULL,
    utc timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    clase integer NOT NULL,
    valor double precision[],
    registro timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    power integer DEFAULT (-1),
    voltaje double precision DEFAULT 0.0
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY historico
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_telemetria_data_clase_id FOREIGN KEY (clase) REFERENCES clase(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Sample data**

```
      imei       |         utc         | clase |     valor      |           registro            | power | voltaje 
-----------------+---------------------+-------+----------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------
 354677050164513 | 2015-11-17 14:20:52 |    86 | {525,217,53,1} | 2015-11-17 14:21:04.238665+00 |     1 |       1
```

**Structure table A**

```
telemetria_data.clase 

CREATE TABLE clase (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(100),
    estructura integer[],
    descripcion text
);
```

**Sample data**

```
 id |    nombre    |  estructura   | descripcion 
----+--------------+---------------+-------------
 86 | Caiquen - E4 | {35,34,20,21} | Telemetria
```

**Structure table B**

```
telemetria_data.clase_parametro;

CREATE TABLE clase_parametro (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(50),
    descripcion text,
    unidad integer
);
```

**Sample data**

```
 id |                   nombre                   |                descripcion                 | unidad 
----+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------
 20 | Numero Energizacion                        | Numero Energizacion                        |      0
 21 | Numero de Partida                          | Numero de Partida                          |      0
 34 | Tiempo trayecto en que se inicia el evento | Tiempo trayecto en que se inicia el evento |     15
 35 | Duracion del Evento                        | Duracion del Evento                        |     15
```

Actual data is column 'valor' from table telemetria_data.historico_354677050164513, that table is related to table 'clase' using the clase and id columns, and 'clase' table is related to 'clase_parametro' using the estructura and id columns.  (I hope this explanation is clear enough

Can you please provide hints on the needed JOIN to get data out of the "data table" with proper "column" names (from clase_parametro.nombre) for each of the items in the "historico_354677050164513.valor" column?

PS 1: I know normalization would help, but that's not actually doable in our scenario, where we already have tons of data stored.

PS 2: I've read several articles / questions regarding similar subjects, but could find a way to join all 3 tables.

Comment: Are you asking how to specify a matching condition between a value and an array of values? Have you tried `SingleValueColumn IN (ArrayColumn)`?

Comment: @AndriyM that's not useful in this scenario, as the 'valor' column from the 'historico' table has no direct relation with the other tables, it only preserves the array internal order of the clase.estructura column, that's why I think I need something to deal with arrays using indexes or something like that

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding this part of your explanation: *"Actual data is column 'valor' from table telemetria_data.historico_354677050164513, that table is related to table 'clase' using the clase and id columns, and 'clase' table is related to 'clase_parametro' using the estructura and id columns."* I thought that meant that `historico_354677050164513.valor` values were arrays of references to `clase.id`, and similarly `clase.estructura` values were arrays of references to `clase_parametro.id`. Did I indeed misunderstand that?

Comment: Yes @AndriyM you did misunderstood that. The `valor` column in no reference to no column, is has the actual data value, in the sample data provided the first array item in `valor` is **525**, as it is the first index, it mean it's related to the first item in the estructura` column from the `clase` table, that's a **35** and that value DOES references `id` column from table `clase_parametro` (nombre='Duracion del Evento'). So it means that it has a 'Duracion del evento = 525'. Better explained now?

Comment: Ah yes, I think I get it now. `historico_354677050164513.clase` is a reference to `clase.id`. Each data item in the `historico_354677050164513.valor` array is related to an item in the corresponding position of `clase.estructura`. The items in the `clase.estructura` array are, in turn, references to `clase_parametro.id`. And you want the `clase_parametro.nombre` values to become captions (column headers) for the matching `historico_354677050164513.valor` items. Is that correct?

Comment: @AndriyM absolutely right! A bit complex, but I guess there might some way to correlate array indexes in the tables involved to solve this query out